# Python 3 - reading text from a file

Tags: python

This is exercise 15 from Learn Python the Hard Way, but I'm using **Python 3**.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)
print ("Here's your file %r:") % filename
print txt.read()

print ("I'll also ask you to type it again:")
file_again = input()
txt_again = open(file_again)
print txt_again.read()
```

**file is saved as ex15.py, and when I run it from terminal it reads ex15.txt correctly first time, but when I request it second time, I get an error**

```
user@user:~/Desktop/python$ python ex15.py ex15.txt<br>
Here's your file 'ex15.txt':<br>
This is stuff I typed into a file.<br>
It is really cool stuff.<br>
Lots and lots of fun to have in here.<br>

I'll also ask you to type it again:<br>
ex15.txt <b>#now I type this in again, and I get a following error</b><br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "ex15.py", line 11, in <<module>module><br>
    file_again = input()<br>
  File "<<string\>string>", line 1, in <<module>module><br>
NameError: name 'ex15' is not defined
```

What's wrong?

Comment: for python 3 you would need to use `print()` function instead of `print` statement and [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of `%` => you are not using python 3, check the default interpreter for `.py` files of your operating system

Comment: Agree on print(), but you can still use the % operator on strings in CPython 3.x.  For dual version code, using % can be a good thing.  Also pylint checks it well for type issues.

Answer (score 6):

You're definitely not using Python 3. There's a couple things that make this obvious:

- These `print` statements don't have parenthesis (which are required in Python 3 but not 2):

  ```
  print ("Here's your file %r:") % filename
  print txt.read()

  print txt_again.read()
  ```
- This is calling [`eval` on `input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) which was [changed in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#input):

  ```
  file_again = input()
  ```

Most likely Python 2 is the default on your system, but you can make your script always use Python 3 by adding this as the first line of your script (if you're running it directly, like `./myscript.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Or running it explicitly with Python 3:

```
python3 myscript.py
```

One more note: You should really close the file when you're done with it. You can either do this explicitly:

```
txt = open(filename)
# do stuff needing text
txt.close()
```

Or use a [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and have it handled when the block ends:

```
with open(filename) as txt:
    # do stuff needing txt
# txt is closed here
```

Comment: +1 For going the length to explain the differences between versions, for which ever one the OP may really be using.

Answer (score 4):

Your print statement suggests you're not using py3k as you said in your title.

`print txt.read()` this doesn't works in py3k, so make sure you're actually using py3k.

you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` because you're on `py 2.x`.

example py 2.x:

```
>>> x=raw_input()
foo
>>> x=input()   # doesn't works as it tries to find the variable bar
bar                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

example py 3.x:

```
>>> x=input()
foo
>>> x       # works fine
'foo'
```

Comment: no, python 3 does not have raw_input. It was renamed to `input`

Comment: but his `print` statement suggest he's not using py3k.

Comment: But his title and his first line say he is using python 3

Comment: @jdi I think the title is misleading, otherwise `print txt.read()` should not have worked.

Comment: He is also new to python, so it is a safe to assume he may have made a mistake in regards to the version of python he is using.

Comment: If the OP is indeed using python2.x, then I will vote this answer up since it would be correct.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary you've convinced me, your answer is probably correct, he might not know what version of python he is using.

Comment: I think the down votes were because your original answer purely gave a python2.x solution without clarifying that you think they are running the wrong one. But I just added a +1 FWIW

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using python 3.0..
to check this, just type into the terminal window:

`python`

and look at the info lines that appear when the interperator starts.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

It should way something like this,
for `python 2.7.3`, and for `python 3.X.X` it would say `python 3.X.X` instead.

If you are using python 2.X, `Ashwini Chaudhary` has the correct answer.

Comment: his `print txt.read()` actually worked fine, so he's surely not using py3k.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, for py3k:

```
txt = open(filename, 'r')
print('Here\'s your file %r: ' % filename)
print(txt.read())
txt.close()

print('I\'ll also ask you to type it again: ')
file_again = input()
txt_again = open(file_again, 'r')
print(txt_again.read())
txt_again.close()
```